# Semantic HTML5: footer tag position

Tags: html, semantics

I got something like that:

```
<div>
    <header>
        //My content
    </header>
    <nav>
        //My nav
    </nav>

    <footer>
        //My footer content
    </footer>
</div>
```

Is it semantically correct to move my *footer* tag outside the *div id="page"* so to have:

```
<div>
    <header>
        //My content
    </header>
    <nav>
        //My nav
    </nav>
</div>
<footer>
  //My footer content
</footer>
```

I think yes, but not 100% sure. I accept advices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how you interpret the [definition of the footer tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/footer.html):

> A footer typically contains information about its section such as who wrote it, links to related documents, copyright data, and the like.

Personally, I'd use the first example. The contents of the `<div>` act as one section of your document.

Comment: I would use the first one too, but keep with current markup(first one) will give me a big headache on solving an issue that I can solve in few minutes with the second example. Since technically there's nothing wrong I would like to know if there's something wrong on taking it out the div.

Comment: @Senbee: Nope, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Following the W3C specs I can't see anything wrong on putting footer outside div.